# CancellationTokens for ReadDocumentAsync

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is there any proper way of canceling a running task against CosmosDb?

I'm calling my API that uses CancellationToken, when receiving data from the DocumentClient there does not seem to be a way of utilizing the tokens in a proper way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versions before 2.0.0 for `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` don't have support for `CancellationToken` on the `ReadDocumentAsync`.

However [Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core 2.0.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core/) just got released and it does have support for `CancellationToken` for all it's CRUD operations.